# mysql  trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I need the right syntax for mysql trigger I'm using version 5.1
and the syntax error alwys apper when I wrote  sql statment

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  blood_year
AFTER INSERT ON donor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO blood_donation (donation_year)VALUES 
(YEAR(NOW()));
 END$$
```

any idea??

Comment: Can you post the error message you get aswell ?

Comment: Is it really the whole code? I'm sorry, but it doesn't make much sense to me: you insert a single '2012' to some other table each time someone inserts a row into `donor`. Shouldn't these table be linked in some way or another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another "DELIMITER" statement at the end:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  blood_year
AFTER INSERT ON donor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO blood_donation (donation_year)VALUES (YEAR(NOW()));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```